# Azure Application Insights CLI event types

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli, azure-media-services

Referencing the Microsoft Azure CLI Docs for Application Insights queries I see a parameter `--type` but I don't see a list of all the available types.

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/app-insights/events?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_app_insights_events_show

For example this command:
`az monitor app-insights events show --app 55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555 --type availabilityResults --start-time "2021-07-01 12:00:00.00" --end-time "2021-07-12 12:00:00.00" -o jsonc`

Has the property  `--type` as `availabilityResults`. What are all the available options for type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those events correspond with the tables you can query using kusto. From [these docs](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-events):

> Available options are standard event types (traces, customEvents, pageViews, requests, dependencies, exceptions, availabilityResults